# Delete File and Data from server using php

Tags: php, file, pdo, unlink

For the love of god, I cannot get this work. I am new to php/mysqli(I don't even know anymore) and I am trying to get this to work for the non-profit I am with. I am never going to do this again. I have tried for 3 days and now I have no Idea where I am anymore.

I am trying to upload and download a file then delete it when we don't need it anymore.

Upload and Download works.

I can not get the delete function to work. If my life deepened on it...I would die....

Here is my data base connection:

```
    <?php
    $conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_pdo_download', 'root', '');
    if(!$conn){
        die("Fatal Error: Connection Failed!");
    }
?>
```

Here is the upload/download page:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
    </head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">

        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>    
    <div class="col-md-6 well">
        <h3 class="text-primary">Files</h3>
        <hr style="border-top:1px dotted #ccc;"/>
        <center>
            <form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" required="required"/>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="upload"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </center>
        <br />
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="alert-info">
                <tr>
                    <th>File</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    require 'conn.php';
                    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `file`");
                    $query->execute();
                    while($fetch = $query->fetch()){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $fetch['file']?></td>
                    <td>
                    <a href="download.php?file_id=<?php echo $fetch['file_id']?>" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>

                    <!--Not Working-->
                        <a href="delete.php?file_id=<?php echo $fetch['file']?>" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
                    <!--Not Working-->

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is my upload function:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'conn.php';

    if(ISSET($_POST['upload'])){
        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $exp = explode(".", $file_name);
        $ext = end($exp);
        $time = date("d-m-Y");
        $name = $time."-".$file_name;
        $path = "uploads/".$name;

        if($file_size > 5242880){
            echo "<script>alert('File too large')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
        }else{
            try{                
                if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $path)){
                    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `file` (`file`, `location`) VALUES ('$name', '$path')";
                    $conn->exec($sql);
                }

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

            $conn = null;

            header('location:index.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is my delete file…..not working:

```
 <?php
//connect to data 
require 'conn.php';



//what am I doing wrong here
//Trying to get the file to delete
$fileToDelete = $_GET['file_id'];

//Deleting that row using a prepared statement?
$sql = "DELETE FROM `file` WHERE `file_id` = :file";

//Prepare our DELETE statement.
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

//The make that we want to delete from our cars table.
$makeToDelete = $fileToDelete;

//Bind our $makeToDelete variable to the paramater :make.
$statement->bindValue(':file', $makeToDelete);

//Execute our DELETE statement.
$delete = $statement->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Does `<?php echo $fetch['file']?>` have value? What does the rest show, did you look at your HTML source? Are you checking for errors at all?

Comment: Why is this tagged as "mysqli" and "phpmyadmin"?

Comment: I have no idea how to  tag this. $fileToDelete = $_GET['file_id']; is undefined var....I am just so frustrated at this point....

Comment: Visit these 2 pages and apply it to your code. 1) https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php for the PDO. and 2) https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - I fixed the tags. Now, do that and then come back and tell us what errors you got back, if any. And again as I said earlier, look at your HTML source. "That", is actually a coder's/developer's tool, believe it or not. Once you've done that, edit your post and we'll take a look at it and try to help you out, *deal?*

Comment: Wait a minute. Your connection variable in your file is `$conn`, but you used `$pdo` in the deletion page. Error reporting would have signaled an undefined variable notice and PDO error checking would have thrown you another.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\delete.php on line 15
The error I am geting is
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\delete.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\delete.php on line 15 i